# Why was StandardRB gem not able to format files in a directory, when multiple apps loaded into a VSCode workspace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, rubygems

Forgive the poor wording of the top level question, or I'm open to revisions.

With 2 projects open in an Untitled VSCode workspace, I lost the ability to format files in `project_a/`.

`project_a/` is a Rails app using the `Standard` gem for formatting/styling.

Because `project_b/` was also in the workspace, VSCode was not able to make the connection to the Language Server Provider for `Standard`.

So why was my ability to apply formatting in the IDE regained after I removed `project_b/` from the VSCode workspace?